# PHP-Like syntax for classes

Tags: c++, oop, object

I'm just wondering whether this is possible or not in C++.

In PHP (frameworks) I sometimes see classes (objects) and methods within the class being accessed by:

```
$this->encrypt->decode($msg, $key);
```

In one of my programs I have the following:

```
Directory *d = new Directory("dir");
d->open();
```

Is it possible to have instead:

```
Directory *d = new Directory("dir")->open();
```

So the two methods can be executed in the same line?

Comment: `Directory("dir").open();`, but you can't fit a variable declaration in there.

Comment: Actually, you could technically make `open` return `*this` to unnecessarily use `Directory d(Directory("dir).open());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code `$this->encrypt->decode($msg, $key);` is calling the `decode()` method on `encrypt` within the current class.

The code you have is performing a different task of initialising a class and then calling it.

In the same way you couldn't do this in PHP:

```
$test = new Test()->method();
```

.. you can't do it in C++ either, no. You would not expect an instance of `Test` in `$test` in this case, it would instead be the return of `method()` on a newly instantiated test object.

That said, you can indeed inline it like you say if you only needed the return value of `open()` (or nothing at all) and not the instance of `Directory`:

```
Directory("dir").open();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) So it wouldn't be possible to have.. "d->open()->files();"? Instead of creating a new instance, that was a bad example to give (on my part).

Comment: @Phorce that should be possible, so long as `.open()` returned an instance of itself. Still, your PHP example is different.

Answer (score 1):

no, that isn't possible unless the Directory class was set up to support this explicitly. this usually involves making most of the methods in the class return references to itself so that you can chain method calls together.

your php example is totally different though. the C++ version of the example you posted would be:

```
Directory("dir").open();
```

with no capture of the Directory instance returned with `Directory("dir")`